# JavaScript addEventListener add a reference to the current object

Tags: javascript, scope, dom-events

I have simplified my code to illustrate the problem.

```
function SnakeGame ()
{
    this.snakeDirection         = 'right';

    this.Init = function ()
    {
        window.addEventListener('keydown', this.keyboardInput, false);
    }

    this.keyboardInput = function (event, SnakeGameObject)
    {
        console.log(SnakeGameObject); //Error since I can't pass this variable...
        console.log(event.keyCode); //Works
    }
}
```

Within the this.keyboardInput function I try to change the variable this.snakeDirection; problem is that I can't get a reference to the SnakeGame object. Within the keyboardInput function this refers to window. I understand why it refers to window, but I can't think of a solution...

The full code can be seen here: http://eriknijland.nl/stackoverflow/snake_event_listener/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though Mythril's answer is correct, I'd suggest you not to use methods as event callbacks. Because: a) they're public, so can be overruled quite easily once your code gets bigger and b) they're publicly accessible:

```
var snakeInstance = new SnakeGame();
var otherObject = new SomethingElse();
snakeInstance.keyboardInput.apply(otherObject,[]);//invokes method, uses self, though self !== otherObject, but snakeInstance.
```

So I'd use a closure:

```
function SnakeGame()
{
    this.snakeDirection = 'right';
    var keyBoardInput = (function(that)
    {
        return function(e)
        {
            console.log(that);
            console.log(e.keyCode);
        }
    })(this);
    this.Init = function()
    {
        document.body.addEventListener('keydown',keyboardInput,false);
    }
}
```

Also bear in mind that your code isn't exactly X-browser compatible (addEventListener && attachEvent?)

Comment: This line is what I was looking for: "})(this);" thanks a lot!! I've been reading so many JavaScript tutorials today. And most of them use the wrong approach... Thanks thanks thanks! Plus I know about the browser compatibility I'm just experimenting and refreshing my JavaScript knowledge haven't used it for years...

Comment: Wow, that's unnecessarily complicated.  All properties are "public" in JS - get over it!

Comment: @Alnitak: DC wouldn't like the way I code (jslint spews warnings about messy whitespace and doesn't like the `})(this);` line one bit (suggests: `}(this))`) but I take your comment as a complement anyway: DC knows JS like few other people, so yes I do take his advice to heart

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I actually withdrew that comment, as I remember that DC is one of those that objects to people trying to do C++/Java style hiding of "private" properties or methods.  Your code would have been much simpler with a local function and then `.bind` to set the context.

Comment: @Alnitak: Nope, you shouldn't JS is a functional language, so using the powers it has to offer (_Like Lambda functions, closures and what have you_) is what you should do, rather than using it as a skimmed subset of Java (which is isn't)

Comment: @Alnitak: My snippet is kept as closely as possible to the OP's current script, I wouldn't write this code myself. But I must say: you're wrong there: DC gave talks where he used a similar example to show how to make methods/properties private, and he wrote a lot of the `YUI` code, which is full of this kind of constructs

Answer (score 1):

If targeting ES5 (and you should be), you should write:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', this.keyboardInput.bind(this), false);
```

which will ensure that the callback is always called with `this` as its context.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function SnakeGame ()
{
    var self = this;
    this.snakeDirection         = 'right';

    this.Init = function ()
    {
        window.addEventListener('keydown', this.keyboardInput, false);
    }

    this.keyboardInput = function (event)
    {
        console.log(self); 
        console.log(event.keyCode); //Works
    }
}
```

Comment: Using name 'self' is a bad practice. 'self' - link to window. Use 'that' instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.self

Comment: wtf are you on about @jinsky? self is an arbitrary var name, for all I care, OP can call it _io_, if he's Spanish, and it makes sense...

Comment: Well self works and my snake finally listens to my keyboard. So thanks for the help. BUT I'm guessing there is another way as well? I've read about anonymous functions in combination with the event listener but my brain gave up on that one...

Comment: @Erik, I was just typing an answer that uses closures :P I assumed you'd used them before, so I did't provide all that much explanation, so if you want, I could elaborate a bit on that approach